# PhpStorm - Exclude directory from "ctrl + shift + n" command

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I am working with Symfony. Every time I use "ctrl+shift+n" to go to a file, PhpStorm is looking into every `vendors` to try to find the file and thus spoils the prompt with irrelevant suggestions.

[image: Prompt spoiled with irrelevant suggestions]

A solution I have tried is to exclude the `vendors` directory from the project, the problem is I can't dig anymore on a specific class nor use the suggestions associated with classes in the vendors` folder.

Has anyone faced the same issue ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your only option right now is to do what you did -- exclude folders from `vendors` directory. You just need to do it a bit differently -- you still need to reference it back...

1. Instead of excluding the whole folder, exclude specific subfolders (e.g. `vendors/symfony`)
2. Add such folder back via Include Paths (`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Languages & Frameworks | PHP`)

In theory -- excluding whole `vendor` folder and then adding it back via Include Paths will also work .. but I prefer having a bit better control and do it on individual packages/vendors level.

Plus, the Composer integration does basically the same (if such option is enabled) but will do it on actual package level (`vendors/symfony/symfony`) instead of proposed here upper vendor level (`vendors/symfony`).

---

After you do this you will see results from such excluded folders ONLY if there will be no matches in actual project files... or if you enable inclusion of non-project matches.

---

If you are using Composer ... just enabling that option should be enough (you need to provide path top your `composer.json` for that, of course)

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2020-08-15:** Since 2020.1 or so you can use Scopes in <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> popup and alike (Search Everywhere, navigate to File/Class/Symbol/etc).

P.S. It may not be remembered between IDE sessions (there are tickets about that) but definitely remembered in the same session.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. No need to use scopes as pretty much everyone else says to do.

Comment: I dont see CombinedScopes or the other choices in that lasat screenshot.The last grouping is Data Sources

Comment: @MosheWeitzman Those are **my custom scopes** that I have created in that project. Different icons (with arrow and without) mean local and shared. 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-scopes.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html