# PHPStorm exclude vendor from search but keep Intellisense

Tags: phpstorm

Any idea how can I exclude the `vendor` directory from `Search in files and folders` but keep it in indexing for Intellisense purposes?

I need to search only in my Symfony files, not the framework and so on.

Tried `Scopes` in `Settings`, with this pattern:

`!file[abuse]:vendor//*`

Thank you!

Comment: Use Scopes. Just when creating scopes .. ensure that you have inclusive parts as well -- include everything recursively and only then exclude unwanted stuff -- ATM search does not work with scopes that have exclude rules only.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know that I must include everything first. Thanks! Respond to the full question so I can mark as resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scopes functionality is the way to go here.

You just need to ensure that you have inclusive parts as well and not exclude rules only. The solution is to include everything recursively and only then exclude unwanted stuff.

The reason for that -- ATM search does not correctly process scopes that have exclude rules only.

Answer (score 8):

I tried using scopes but it didn't seem to work for me. The `vendor` files still turned up when trying to open files (ctrl + shift + n) and in order to use the scope I had to manually select it from the `find in all files` dialog.

I better solution I found was using the `composer` settings in PhpStom as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696215/phpstorm-exclude-directory-from-ctrl-shift-n-command).

Just add your `composer.json` and `composer.phar` into the `composer` settings and it does the rest for you!