# How to configure "Directories" when using a Symfony project in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony

I use PhpStorm to work on a Symfony project.

In the *File > Settings > Project … > Directories* configuration, I defined the `vendor/` directory as a *Resource root* in order to have auto-completion and as an *Excluded folder* because I want to ignore vendors when performing a search in my project's code.

But my problem is that vendors are still shown in search results.

Here is my current configuration:

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to avoid: results from `vendor/` are shown:

[image]

Here is the PHP configuration:

[image]

I can restrict search by selecting *Scope = Custom* but sometimes I forget to change this. I'm looking for some settings that I can use in my different Symfony2/3 projects.

How should I mark the `vendor/` directory in order to allow PhpStorm to use  it as a resource root and ignore it when performing a search?

And what is the correct configuration for the default directories structure of a Symfony2 project? Here are the default directories after a Symfony 2.8 installation with `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony-2.8 "~2.8"`:

```
app/
  ├ config
  ├ cache
  ├ logs
  └ Resources
src/
  └ AppBundle/
vendor/
web/
```

Here is how I marked the directories at this moment:

```
.idea               [excluded]
app/
  ├ config
  ├ cache           [excluded]
  ├ logs            [excluded]
  └ Resources
src/                [source]
  └ AppBundle/
    └ Tests/        [test source folders]
vendor/             [excluded]
web/
```

Note: I installed the Symfony plugin for PhpStorm, I don't know if this change the IDE behaviour.

Comment: I made a mistake in the bounty message, it should be *the different **directories***.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `vendor` folder is not a resource root. A resource root is a folder where resources such as images and scripts will be served from by the web server.

In your case the only folder that should be marked as a resource root is probably the `web` folder, but ironically, is almost the only one you haven't selected as a resource root. Marking `web` as the resource root means that the absolute URLs `/css/foo.css` and `/images/foo.jpg` could be valid resources served by the web server; you probably want to remove all other folders from resource roots.

It is correct to exclude the `vendor` folder because it is not part of your first-party project code. In order for code completion to work for third-party code you must add the vendor folder as an external library. This can be done by navigating to *Languages & Frameworks* > *PHP* in the options and specifying the vendor folder as an include path.

Comment: What is the context where clicking `[F4]` trigger something? It does nothing for me. Can you please copy the tree shown in my question ion your answer and add the relevant *marks*? It may be useful for other users.

Comment: Any editor context will work if there isn't another modal dialogue being displayed. However, different users may have different key bindings so it's probably not that useful to specify keyboard shortcuts so I will remove it. I'm not copying your ascii diagram into my answer because I don't think that brings any clarity; the text is clear enough.

Comment: For a best performance and configuration use Symfony plugin, https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin

Comment: What is the difference between: `not having the vendor folder in excluded` and `having it in excluded and having it in "Languages & Frameworks > PHP include path"`. Is there a consequence for word research?

Comment: In my case I have vendor/ in Excluded Folders https://snag.gy/EXhMUt.jpg  and vendor/twig/twig is in Languages > PHP > Include path https://snag.gy/WRlZi0.jpg but I still have no auto-completion for Twig_* classes https://snag.gy/zKYf4k.jpg . What's really wrong?

Comment: This is not the case when you are using something like gulp to catenate all JS files and css/scss.

Comment: @Kwadz When exluding te Vendor in PhpStorm it will not recognize the packages in de vendor folder. So PhpStorm then gives a warningline and the autocomplete does not work. When adding it to _Languages & Frameworks > PHP_ it will recognize all the packages.

Comment: @Kwadz Certain PhpStorm functions are context-aware, such as _Find/Replace_ and the _Find Usages_ features. If you do not exclude third-party code then it will be included in your search results by default, and context filters will not work the way you expect. tl;dr: configure things properly or stuff will go wrong.

Comment: Seems useless. As soon as you add vendor folder to "Languages & Frameworks > PHP include path", the excluded vendor folder becomes included again and takes part in searches.

Answer (score 27):

After having used advices from [Quolonel Questions's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685123/2257664), here is a summary of my configuration for Symfony2 (see Symfony3 at the end of this answer):

For auto-completion, use the `vendor/` directory in *Include path*:

[image]

In order to avoid irrelevant results when searching in the project, the following directories have to be ignored:

```
.idea               [excluded]
app/
  ├ cache           [excluded]
  └ logs            [excluded]
vendor/             [excluded]
```

[image]

Here is my full configuration:

```
.idea               [excluded]
app/
  ├ cache           [excluded]
  └ logs            [excluded]
src/                [source]
  └ AppBundle/
    └ */Tests/      [test source folders]
vendor/             [excluded]
web/                [resources root]
```

*Test Source Folders* are optional, if they are defined the will appear in the toolbar:

[image]

---

With the [default configuration for Symfony3](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html), the directories are slightly different:

```
.idea               [excluded]
src/                [source]
tests/              [test source folders]
var/
  ├ cache           [excluded]
  └ logs            [excluded]
vendor/             [excluded]
web/                [resources root]
```

---

Update: after updating my dependencies with `composer update`, PhpStorm perform searches in the `vendor/` directory, even if these directories are *ignored*. The solution is to remove all the `vendor/*` directories from *Include path* and keep only `vendor/` directory, as on the first screenshot.

I'll have to test if marking all the `vendor/*` directories as *ignored* can work and avoid to repeat this after each time `composer update` is used.

Answer (score 3):

Another option which is easier than manually excluding `vendor` and then including it again in php settings, is to tell PhpStorm about `composer.json` and `composer.phar` in the composer settings as showin in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696215/phpstorm-exclude-directory-from-ctrl-shift-n-command).

Comment: While it still automatically adds all vendor paths as include paths like we want here, the composer plugin gives a warning when using a remote interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

I use PhpStorm 10 as my primary IDE for Symfony2. You don't need to install any Symfony plugins, because PhpStorm support Symfony2 by default.

- Your should mark your `public_html` directory as a Resource Root, or whatever you have that is going to be public
- Sources - your `app/` directory
- If you don't want `vendors/` in search, that's what I exclude also, you press on vendor and "Excluded" button on the top. You also want to exclude, `tmp/` and `app/cache/` directories
- As you already know, you can define scope and search there.

When you exclude directory, it also helps performance since PhpStorm not indexing and watching files there, something you don't want anyway.

As for directory structure of Symfony2, it's pretty flexible, I use my own. Here is [Symfony 2.8 directory](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/quick_tour/the_architecture.html) structure from the docs.

Excluded folders for me are:

- `app/DoctrineMigrations`
- `app/cache`
- `app/logs/`
- `tmp/`

Comment: There's an excellent Symfony plugin for phpStorm that provides a lot of benefit.